# Why is navbar missing an option?

Tags: javascript, html, css, uinavigationbar

I'm making a navbar menu that when viewed on mobile looks like an accordion on desktop, which works fine, but when I'm on mobile when I click on the drop instead of showing all the items it always shows me one less than I should have.

I am new to design in general I would like to know where my error is since I see in the first item it doubles the height and as it moves the last element.

Thanks for any answer or indication that you can give me.

```js
//DROPDOWM MENU FULL SIZE/ MOBILE
const dropdownbtn = document.querySelectorAll('.dropbtn');
const dropdowmContenido = document.querySelectorAll('.drop_contenido');



for (let i = 0; i < dropdownbtn.length; i++) {
    dropdownbtn[i].addEventListener('click',()=>{
      dropdowmContenido[i].classList.toggle("mostrar");
    }); 
}






// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
      let dropdowmCont =  document.querySelectorAll('.drop_contenido');
       // var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowmCont.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowmCont[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('mostrar')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('mostrar');
          }
        }
    }
}



//RESPONSIVE
const btnOpciones= document.querySelector('#btnOpciones');
const opciones = document.querySelector('#opciones');

const btnUser=document.querySelector('#btnUser');
const opcionesUser = document.querySelector('#opcionesUser');

//BOton de opciones
btnOpciones.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  if (opcionesUser.classList.contains('vermenu')) {
    opcionesUser.classList.remove('vermenu');
  } 
  opciones.classList.toggle('vermenu');
});


//Boton de Usuario
btnUser.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  if (opciones.classList.contains('vermenu')) {
    opciones.classList.remove('vermenu');
  } 
  opcionesUser.classList.toggle('vermenu');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;500&display=swap');


*, body, html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

:root{
    --navbar-alto: 35px;
    --navbar-ancho:100vw;
    --navbar-color: rgb(228, 226, 226);

    --navbar-texto-color: rgb(129, 129, 129);
    --navbar-texto-fuente-tamaño: 16px;

    --navbar-hover-color: rgb(218, 216, 216);
    --navbar-hover-fuente-color: rgb(19, 19, 19);

    --navbar-titulo-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/* Barra Navegacion */
.nav__bar{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    width: var(--navbar-ancho);
    height: var(--navbar-alto);
    background-color: var(--navbar-color);
    display: flex; 
    font-size: var(--navbar-texto-fuente-tamaño);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px  rgb(105, 105, 105);
}

/* Estilo para los link */
.nav__bar .nav_item{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #0a0a0a;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: var(--navbar-texto-fuente);
}


/*************
SECCION CON LOS ITEMS DEL MENU  
**************/
/* DROPDOWN */
.dropdown{
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* opciones del dropdown Menu */
.drop_contenido{
   /* display: none;
   */ position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    top: var(--navbar-alto);
}

/* opcion para mostrar el submenu */
.drop_contenido.mostrar{
  /* display: block;
*/}

/* opciones del submenu */
.subNavItem{
    color: black;
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

/* Hover para items y subitems */
.nav_item:hover, 
.dropdown:hover, 
.subNavItem:hover{
    background-color: var(--navbar-hover-color);
    color: var(--navbar-hover-fuente-color);
}

/*Items de la barra de navegacion*/
.items, 
.acciones_extra{
    height: var(--navbar-alto);
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
}

/*Posiciono las acciones extras*/
.acciones_extra{
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px; 
}

/* Icono de los items*/
.item_icon{
    margin-right: 5px;
}

/*dato sque aparace en span*/
.subDato{
    color: green;
    font-size: 15px;
}



/*************
SECCION TITULO DEL SISTEMA O PAGINA     
**************/
.titulo_logo{
    height: var(--navbar-alto);
    width: 240px;
    display: flex;
    text-justify: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo{
    height:calc(var(--navbar-alto) - 5px);
    width: calc(var(--navbar-alto) - 5px);
    max-height: var(--navbar-alto);
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.titulo{
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--navbar-titulo-color);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: calc(var(--navbar-texto-fuente-tamaño) + 5px);
}

.icon_menu,
.icon_user{
    display: none;
}

.icon{
    color: black;
}

/*******************************************
 RESPONSIVE     
*******************************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* ICONOS */
    .icon{
        height: var(--navbar-alto); 
        padding: 10px;  
    }

    .icon:hover{
        background-color: var(--navbar-hover-color);
    }
    
    .icon_menu,
    .icon_user{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        color: black;
    }

    .icon_menu{
        right: 0px;
    }
    
    .icon_user{
        left: 0px; 
    }

    /* BARRA NAVEGACION */
    .nav__bar{
        position: relative;
    } 

    /* TITULO Y LOGO  */
    .titulo_logo{
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
    }

    /* Items y datos de usuario y sistema*/
    .items, 
    .acciones_extra{
        position: absolute;/*con esto se logra que el menu ancho no interfiera con el contenido de arriba */
        background-color: var(--navbar-color);
        width: 100%;
        top: var(--navbar-alto);
        height: auto;
        display: none;
    }

    /* Clase para poder mostrar las opciones del menu general */
    .items.vermenu,  
    .acciones_extra.vermenu{
        display: block;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    /*Forma de mostrar los items en el menu responsive*/
    .nav_item{
        width: 100%;    
    }

    /* Contenido del submenu */
    .drop_contenido{
       position: relative;
    }


    .subNavItem{
        text-align: center;
        border: 0.1px solid yellow;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar-submenu.css">
     <!-- CARGA FONT AWESOME-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="nav__bar">
        <a href="#" class="icon_menu icon" id="btnUser"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="icon_user icon" id="btnOpciones"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>

        <!--SECCION TITULO DEL SISTEMA O PAGINA-->
     
        <div class="titulo_logo">
            <img src="logo.jpg" alt="" class="logo">
            <a href="#" class="titulo">Mi Aplicacion</a>
        </div>
          
        <!--SECCION CON LOS ITEMS DEL MENU -->
     
        <div class="items" id="opciones">
            <a href="#" class="nav_item">Inico</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav_item">Seccion B</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav_item dropbtn">Drop 1</a>
                <div class="drop_contenido">
                    <a href="#" class="subNavItem">sub 1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="subNavItem">sub 2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="subNavItem">sub 3</a>
                    <a href="#" class="subNavItem">sub 4</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="nav_item">Contacto</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav_item dropbtn">drop 2</a>
                <div class="drop_contenido">
                    <a href="#" class="subNavItem">submenu 1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="subNavItem">sub 2</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav_item dropbtn">Drop 3</a>
                <div class="drop_contenido">
                    <a href="#" class="subNavItem">submenu 1 </a>
                    <a href="#" class="subNavItem">sub 2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="subNavItem">sub 3</a>
                    <a href="#" class="subNavItem">submenu 4</a>
                </div>
            </div>
           


        </div><!--/ FIN Items-->
  
        <!--SECCION PARA LOS DATOS DEL USUARIO Y CERRAR SESIOn-->
        <div class="acciones_extra" id="opcionesUser">
            <a href="#" class="nav_item"><i class="fas fa-user item_icon"></i>Pedro Peres <span class="subDato">(administrador)</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="nav_item"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt item_icon"></i>Cerrar Sesion</a>
        </div><!--fin acciones extras-->
    </nav>




    <script src="navbarSubmenu.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue you are talking about can be fixed by doing to this removing top from a class and moving the menu out of a div.
you need to remove top from the .drop_contenido class:

```
.drop_contenido{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    /* remove this --> top: var(--navbar-alto);*/
}
```

And you need to extract the menu item from the drop down menu:

```
<a href="#" class="nav_item dropbtn">Drop 1</a>
<!-- place the drop item outside the dropdown div --> 
<div class="dropdown">
    <!-- Remove the Drop item from here --> 
    <div class="drop_contenido">
        <a href="#" class="subNavItem">sub 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="subNavItem">sub 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="subNavItem">sub 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="subNavItem">sub 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If this solves you question please mark the question as complete

Comment: thanks work fine in mobile now,  but in desktop now the menu move to the right.and i dont now why.

Comment: @NicolasRossi its bad practice to use absolute position for this sort of things. And that is probably part of the cause. You should be using flex box and or grid and and that's the real problem. Does that answer your question and resolve your issue?